# Trouble testing if Redux-Toolkit's AsyncThunks have been called

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I started testing an app of mine recently and am running into issues when trying to test if a component's `useEffect` dispatches certain `asyncThunk` actions.

My test (uses `redux-mock-store` for the store):

```
it('should dispatch actions', () => {
        expect.hasAssertions();
        const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch');
        const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn();
        useDispatchSpy.mockReturnValue(mockDispatchFn);

        mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Dashboard />
            </Provider>,
        );

        expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
        expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fetchCurriculumPrefixes());
        expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fetchHeatmap(''));
        expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fetchCurriculumFromPrefix(''));
        expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(syncTimetable({
            timetable: [], timestamp: '',
        }));
        useDispatchSpy.mockClear();
    });
```

The test fails with a very uninformative error:

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: [Function anonymous]
    Received
           1: [Function anonymous]
           2: [Function anonymous]
           3: [Function anonymous]

    Number of calls: 4

      62 |              expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
    > 63 |              expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fetchCurriculumPrefixes());
         |                                     ^
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make sure certain dispatches are called in the component. Testing the thunk itself is not an issue, since its a simple API call.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Testing without the mocked `dispatch` function results in `redux-mock-store` throwing an error: `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

I can try testing by adding `redux-thunk`, but does not seem ideal to add a dependency to only use for a test.